# How to parse variable in wunderground api url with HTTPParty?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Use wunderground API to show weather forecast on my city pages.

city_controller.rb

```
def show

        @region = Region.find(params[:region_id])
        @city = City.find(params[:id])

        @weather_lookup = WeatherLookup.new

end
```

weather_lookup.rb

```
class WeatherLookup 
    attr_accessor :temperature, :icon, :condition

    def fetch_weather
      HTTParty.get("http://api.wunderground.com/api/a8135a01b8230bfb/hourly10day/lang:NL/q/IT/#{@city.name}.xml")
     end

    def initialize
      weather_hash = fetch_weather
    end

    def assign_values(weather_hash)
      hourly_forecast_response = weather_hash.parsed_response['response']['hourly_forecast']['forecast'].first
      self.temperature = hourly_forecast_response['temp']['metric']
      self.condition = hourly_forecast_response['condition']
      self.icon = hourly_forecast_response['icon_url']

   end

   def initialize
    weather_hash = fetch_weather
    assign_values(weather_hash)
   end

end
```

show.html.haml(city)

```
= @weather_lookup.temperature 
= @weather_lookup.condition.downcase 
= image_tag @weather_lookup.icon
```

To fetch to correct weather forecast i thought that i can place the @city variable in the HTTParty.get URL as i did in the example, But i get the error message undefined method `name'

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the city in WeatherLookup you are going to need to pass it to the initializer. Instance variables are only bound to their respective views.

```
@weather_lookup = WeatherLookup.new(@city)
```

---

```
attr_accessor :city # optional

def initialize(city)
  @city = city
  weather_hash = fetch_weather
end
```

Comment: i get the error message: wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)app/models/weather_lookup.rb:21:in `initialize'